# One piece of my model turned to transparent in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I came up to a problem where one part of my design appeared transparent once I switch my render engine in the rendered view from Eevee to Cycles.

[image]

https://prnt.sc/w0yo88

I have checked every layer to see whether I have ticked off any of them, but it seems that everything is OK. why is that happening and how to fix that? and is it something with my video card or it is just a glitch with Blender 2.90.1

Comment: maybe share your file (only the part that gets transparent)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: does this happen on cpu render as well?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Pirinipled BSDF (texture) has Alpha on 1.

I know you have yours on all the way but I'm leaving this comment for
any new comers who have an invisibility issue.